# output an array in php inside EOD

Tags: php

I have the following php script:

```
<?php

$favorites = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `the_comment_id`='{$row['comments_id']}'  ");    

while($e = mysql_fetch_array($favorites)){
    $like_users = $e['user'];
    $array[]=$like_users;
}

$comments .= <<<EOD
<table><td> PRINT ARRAY HERE {$array[0]} </td></table>  
EOD;
?>
```

is it possible to print all array contents inside the EOD; I used {$array[0]} but prints me only the first array contente of course. How can I change it to print me all content of array? Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your array and then pass it inside the `HEREDOC` ?

```
$arstring = implode(' ',$array); //<--- Implode your array with space as the delimiter
$comments .= <<<EOD
<table><td> $arstring </td></table>  
EOD;
?>
```

Comment: great...but on last question... if i want to use </br> to output contents on different lines any idea how to do this?

Comment: Simply add the `<br>` inside of the `implode` function like this. `$arstring = implode('<br/>',$array);`